# How to send data from esp8266 to my nodejs web app or from raspberry pi to node js app server

Tags: node.js, arduino, raspberry-pi, esp8266

I need to send data of sensor to my nodejs server from either nodeMCU(esp8266) or raspberrypi. any sugessions ?

Comment: "any suggestion"? It is a web client (your ESP8266) server (your nodejs) relationship. know how to google it?

Comment: I suggest you use Google. There are thousands of tutorials about how to do this kind of thing out there.